# How to filter the data coming from the API and display on the TableView in swift?

Tags: json, swift, api, filter, tableview

I am trying to receive API data from Finnhub and put it in a table view.

The API data I am using is Symbol Lookup, which is an API that receives the company's detailed name and stock symbol.

It's API data that gets the names of all companies in the world, and I want to filter only US-related company stocks and assign them to a table view. Only US-related Company.

How to filter the data coming from the API and display on the TableView?

Here's my code

```
enum CompanyDataNetworkError: Error {
    case networkingError
    case dataError
    case parseError
}


final class CompanyDataManager {
    

    static let shared = CompanyDataManager()

    private init() {}
    
    
    typealias NetworkCompletion = (Result<[CompanyDataResult], CompanyDataNetworkError>) -> Void

  
    func fetchNetwork(searchTerm: String, completion: @escaping NetworkCompletion) {
        
        let myAPIKey = "myAPIKey"
        let urlString = "https://finnhub.io/api/v1/search?q=\(searchTerm)&token=\(myAPIKey)"
        print(urlString)
        
        performRequest(with: urlString) { result in
            completion(result)
        }
        
    }
    

    private func performRequest(with urlString: String, completion: @escaping NetworkCompletion) {
        //print(#function)
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                completion(.failure(.networkingError))
                print("DEBUG: Network Error")
                return
            }
            
            guard let safeData = data else {
                completion(.failure(.dataError))
                print("DEBUG: Data Error")
                return
            }
            

            if let company = self.parseJSON(safeData) {
                print("Parse Success")
                completion(.success(company))
            } else {
                print("DEBUG: Parse Failure")
                completion(.failure(.parseError))
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    

    private func parseJSON(_ companyData: Data) -> [CompanyDataResult]? {
        print(#function)
    

        do {
            let companyData = try JSONDecoder().decode(CompanyData.self, from: companyData)
            return companyData.result
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            print("DEBUG: JSON Error")
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

```
import UIKit

class SearchResultHomeController: UIViewController {

    
    var companyManager = CompanyDataManager.shared
    

    var searchTerm: String? {
        didSet {
            setupDatas()
        }
    }
    
    
    
    var companyArray: [CompanyDataResult] = []
    
    
    let tableView = UITableView()
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
    }
    
   

    }
    
    
    func setupDatas() {
        
        guard let term = searchTerm else { return }
        
        companyManager.fetchNetwork(searchTerm: term) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let companyDatas):

                self.companyArray = companyDatas

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
       
        
    }
    
}


extension SearchResultHomeController: UITableViewDataSource {
 
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return companyArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SearchResultCell", for: indexPath) as! SearchResultCell
        

        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.textLabel?.text = companyArray[indexPath.row].codeName
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = companyArray[indexPath.row].detailName
        
        
        return cell
        
    }
    
    
}

extension SearchResultHomeController: UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let eachStockDetailVC = EachStockDetailController()
        eachStockDetailVC.searchTerm = companyArray[indexPath.row].codeName
        present(eachStockDetailVC, animated: true)
    }
    
    
}
```

I tried if error.localizedDescription == "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." to make it not be included in the tableview if it is wrong api, but it didn't work out. can anyone please help me...?

Comment: You are getting all data right ?, or you don't get data at all ?

Comment: Do you ask how to request the filtered data from API? If so, the API provider should have documentation on how to do that. If there's no such functionality, you can, e.g., filter your `CompanyDataResult` objects before returning the list from `parseJSON`.

Comment: What do you mean with “wrong api”? As others have asked, is the code downloading and decoding the response working properly, is this question only about filtering the response?

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter to get only US companies. Try this code for example:

```swift
func setupDatas() {

    guard let term = searchTerm else { return }

    companyManager.fetchNetwork(searchTerm: term) { result in
        switch result {
            case .success(let companyDatas):

                self.companyArray = companyDatas.filter { company in
                    company.codeName.contains("US")
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: What is `codeName`?

Comment: @Joakim Danielson I thinks is string because of this: cell.textLabel?.text = companyArray[indexPath.row].codeName

Comment: Oh, so you really have no idea what it contains? Don't you think you could get a lot of false positives when filtering an unknown string like this?

Comment: @JoakimDanielsoni suppose that, but I'm offering a simple answer to a simple question. Filter data. They may validate all of this by your own.

Answer (score 0):

for US exchange stocks only, use `/stock/symbol?exchange=US` api route.  Although, this doesn't allow for search terms like the endpoint your example used, it does get you the US stocks

if you want to search against US stocks, I would suggest using this path, and then creating your own simple search through the data using UISearchBar / UISearchController etc with some kind of pattern matching through the data